# Is it a good idea to declare all text getting used for logging as public static final

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is it a good idea to declare all text getting used for logging as public static final from performance point of view or otherwise ?

Does it have any advantage other than readability in case one string is getting used only once ?

Comment: Is there anything wrong in the way I have asked this question ? Please suggest, I will change it

Comment: "String getting used for logging"--do you mean text values used as log messages? If so, not really--look up String constant interning in Java.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Editing the question to say that explicitly. thanks for commenting

Comment: It might help clean up your code a little by removing the distracting strings. It'll also make it easy to tweak the log messages for a class at a single location. I can't see many problems.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. But from a performance or memory optimization point of view, it hardly makes a difference right ?

Answer (score 3):

First, the objective part of your question: is there a performance benefit from declaring a log statement static final, i.e:

```
private static final String SUCCESS = "Success!";
//[...]
log.info(SUCCESS);
log.info(SUCCESS);
// versus:
log.info("Success!");
log.info("Success!");
```

The JLS states in [section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> [A] string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

So whether your string literal is declared once as a `static final` or appears multiple times in the source code, it will always be the same String *instance*, wherever it is used, and thus take up the same amount of memory, and will be accessed in exactly the same way. There will be no performance difference.

Now the other part of the question: is it a good idea? That is inherently subjective, but my opinion is that you should avoid declaring log messages as `static final`. Log messages add to the readability of the code, which is especially valuable when the code is being maintained by people who did not write it. For example:

```
log.warn(LOGIN_ERROR_OCCURRED, userId, attempt);
// compared to:
log.warn("Login failed for user {}; attempt {} of 5.", userId, attempt);
```

It's much quicker and easier to read the log message in the context of the code, rather than having to jump somewhere else in the code to see the full log message.

Answer (score 1):

Easier internationalization and localization are possible advantages of using identifiers for string constants.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ...
private final static LOGIN_ERROR_OCCURRED = bundle.getString("Login failed for user {}; attempt {} of 5");
```

But the benefits of i18n/L10n for log messages may be questionable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But I did not understand it completely, can you please elaborate it a bit.

Comment: Internationalization (often abbreviated as "i18n", because there are 18 letters between the first and last letters) is making your program work in various languages.  Localization (or, "L10n") extends this to variants of languages.  Allowing your program to display messages and menus in the user's language is a good thing.  Log messages, which are often only read by developers, may not benefit from this, and may make the log useless for the developer if they can't translate it back to their language.  Then again, some programs are developed by an international community.

Comment: An excellent point - internationalization is one of the times it would make sense to use identifiers. I've yet to work on a project that would benefit from internationalized log messages, but that's not to say they don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Logging strings almost certainly should not be declared `public`, at least not usually. In most cases, it's better to declare constant variables for them, but sometimes you can be loose about that. Constants should appear together near the top of the class source, so for logging strings this gives a good overview of what happens in the class. It also makes it easier to find them for maintenance, like to edit out silly extraneous exclamation points. (Don't laugh; I've seen them.) I disagree that they obscure the point of log messages, unless you suck at naming variables. Which far too many people do.